# Decorators around function with *args

Tags: python, function, decorator

I try to learn python decorators, because those things are pretty useful. I understand how simple decorator works, but I have tried to make decorator around function which takes *args and it does not work. For sure I am missing some element. I have been browsing internet looking for answer, but I could not find one.

Inner function adds all integer in the list, wrapper should check if all elements in the list are integers.

```
def wrapper(func):
    def inner(*args):
        for i in range(0, len(args[0])): #It does not iven get there.
            if not isinstance(i, int):
                return 'Invaild values.'
        else:       
            return func(*args)
    return inner

def add(*args):
    result = 0
    for i in range(0, len(args[0])):
        result += args[0][i]
    return result


def main():
    numbers = [1, '2', 3, 4]
    print(add(numbers))
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    print(add(numbers))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrapper_of_function.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "wrapper_of_function.py", line 20, in main
    print(add(numbers))
  File "wrapper_of_function.py", line 15, in add
    result += args[0][i]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Where are you using `wrapper`?

Comment: @Zetys, I am avare of that, purpose of wrapper is to check if there is `str` among `ints`, and if there is, there `'Invaild values'` should be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You test if `i` is instance of int, when you should test if `args[0][i]` is instance of `int` :

```
def wrapper(func):
    def inner(*args):
        for i in range(len(args[0])): #It does not iven get there.
            if not isinstance(args[0][i], int):
                return 'Invalid values.'       
        return func(*args)
    return inner

@wrapper
def add(*args):
    result = 0
    for i in range(0, len(args[0])):
        result += args[0][i]
    return result


def main():
    numbers = [1, '2', 3, 4]
    print(add(numbers))
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    print(add(numbers))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you meant to actually use your decorator

```
def wrapper(func):
    def inner(*args):
        for i in args[0]:
            if not isinstance(i, int):
                raise Exception('a non integer was encountered')
        else:       
            return func(*args)
    return inner

@wrapper
def add(*args):
    total = 0
    for i in args[0]:
        total += i
    return total


def main():
    numbers = [1, '2', 3, 4]
    try:
        print(add(numbers))
    except Exception as e:
        print 'invalid input %r - %s' % (numbers, e)
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    print(add(numbers))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that a weakness of this implementation is that `wrapped` has to have knowledge about what is being passed to it to work properly. It needs to know to check the 0th element. This wont be a very useful function for other purposes. Even though you are using `*args`, you are still only passing a single argument to `add`. You may find `wrapped` generally more useful if you do pass multiple arguments to whatever it decorates.

To do this

```
def wrapper(func):
    def inner(*args):
        for i in args:
            if not isinstance(i, int):
                raise Exception('a non integer was encountered')
        else:       
            return func(*args)
    return inner

@wrapper
def add(*args):
    total = 0
    for i in args:
        total += i
    return total


def main():
    numbers = [1, '2', 3, 4]
    try:
        print(add(*numbers))
    except Exception as e:
        print 'invalid input %r - %s' % (numbers, e)
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    print(add(*numbers))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is solid. We did pretty much the same:)

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use `@wrapper` on `add` function:

```
def wrapper(func):
    def inner(args):
        for item in args:
            if not isinstance(item, int):
               return  'Invalid value found'
        return func(args)
    return inner

@wrapper    
def add(args):
    return sum(args)


def main():
    numbers = [1, '2', 3, 4]
    print(add(numbers))
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    print(add(numbers))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: But this one answer does not outpust the 'Invaild values', when string is passed in the list. However the code is compact and pythonic.

Comment: @frankot I added `'Invalid values'`

Comment: @Zetys so you are going to return an exception?

Comment: @Zetys ok, thanks. It works, but could you explain what 'TypeError' does in this case, besides printing `'invaild values'`. I do not like to use things that I do not understand.

Comment: @frankot `TypeError` is an exception to Raise when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. The associated value is a string giving details about the type mismatch.

Comment: @Zetys yes, but why it is use here like method here, when in `except TypeError:` it is use liked expression. This is the part that is interesting for me. I did not encountered this particular usage of this earlier.

Comment: @Zetys there is no need. I only have wander what is the difference between the option you chose and the classic `except TypeError` concept. Thank for Your help.

Comment: @frankot I am using python exceptions, use of `return string ` is good in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The type error threw is because you can't add an Int and a Str as in [1,'2',3,4]. You decorator should perform a check before the system throw an error but you didn't really use it.

Besides, there a few bugs out there.

```
def wrapper(func):
    def inner(*args):
        # 1, you don't use args other than args[0], what's the point of using list arguments?
        for i in range(0, len(args[0])): #It does not iven get there.
            # 2, you are running isinstance on array indexes, you should run this on values.
            if not isinstance(i, int):
                # 3, it's a bad practice to return different types in different scenarios. Return a special value and print the error message, or just raise a exception
                return 'Invaild values.'
        # 4, else keyword is redundant. the if statement is inside the loop.
        else:       
            return func(*args)
    return inner

# 5, you didn't use wrapper at the first place.
def add(*args):
    result = 0
    # 6, only using the first argument rather than the list
    for i in range(0, len(args[0])):
        result += args[0][i]
    return result
```

I rewrote this piece of code for you and hope it works as you need.

```
def wrapper(func):
    def inner(*args):
        for arg in args:
            if not isinstance(arg, int):
                raise TypeError('Invalid values')
        return func(*args)
    return inner

@wrapper
def add(*args):
    result = 0
    for arg in args:
        result += arg
    return result
```

Check if it works

Comment: Thank you for pointing few things, @4 `else` could be use in that way. @5 I did not, obvious mistake. Your answer does not work.

Comment: @frankot else could be used this way without syntax error but it's sort of unnatural to me. Personal preference I guess. It worked for me. What do you expect from this function?

Comment: It does not work if the list has only integers in it. The error is raised even it should not. The point was to prompt user with message instead to rise an error, because error stops the program.

Comment: @frankot I see. This add function takes several arguments rather than a list. That's what list arguments made for. For instance, if you call add(1,2,3,4), it shall work. if you call add([1,2,3,4]), the argument list *args is actually a list consist of only one list arguments, and will raise the error. Here's the difference, if you are going to take arbitrary parameters, you should use my function. If a list is what you wanted, just use add(alist), rather than add(*args). Regarding exception, I strongly recommend you use try and catch to continue the program rather than yielding a string.

Comment: I see now that I misunderstood the purpose and role of `*args`, thank you for clarifying that out for me. I know that `try` and `catch` is more flexible, but it looked like to much for such simple usage. Moreover Yours comment explained to me why the number list was inside a touple.

Comment: You are more than welcome. If you are going to feed a list into add function you can use add(*alist).

Answer (score 0):

@Zetys : In numbers = [1, '2', 3, 4], the second element is a string
So it can't be added to the `result` because its an `int` (result = 0). If you want that `string` arguments are convert to `int` in case they are numbers, you should use the `int(str)` function. So your code will be:

```
def add(*args):
    result = 0
    for i in range(0, len(args[0])):
        result += int(args[0][i])
    return result
```

BTW, you haven't used `wrapper` class anywhere in the code, so it won't run :)